# linq to entities does not recognize the method int32 toint32

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, entity-framework, int

I get this error when I try to compare int to int (when comparing string it works)

```
IEnumerable<Commune> myCommunes = from d in db.Communes
                                  where d.CodePostal == Convert.ToInt32(CodePostal.Text)
                                  select d;

foreach (Commune c in myCommunes)
{
    CommunesList.Add(c);
}
```

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: Convert the `CodePostal.Text` to an integer before your lINQ call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `CodePostal.Text` is something within your existing context - so all you've got to do is extract that from the query:

```
int code = Convert.ToInt32(CodePostal.Text); // Or use int.Parse...

// Not using a query expression here as it just adds extra cruft
IEnumerable<Commune> myCommunes = db.Communes.Where(d => d.CodePostal == code);
```

It's not clear where `CommunesList` comes from - but if it's empty before this, you could just use:

```
CommunesList = db.Communes.Where(d => d.CodePostal == code).ToList();
```

Comment: just ran into this same problem and this solution helped. Is this because of the way linq is parsing the expression by not converting before executing the query?

Comment: @AndreDublin: Yes - originally the query contained the parsing part, whereas I've separated that out so that it just contains the value.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:
db.Communes.Where(d => d.CodePostal == (int)CodePostal.Text)

Comment: It doesn't compile. I get cannot convert type 'string' to 'int' error.